# Global (process wide) properties in Win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

I am trying to share some data across DLLs in a project which has an extremely complicated dependency structure (numberous DLLs).

I want to be able to associate a key with some data in one part of the application, and then extract that data by supplying the appropriate key in some other part of the app. In a way, one can say that I looking for something that is similar to Java's System.setProperty()/getProperty().

I was sure that the Process APIs would give me some access to a process-wide buffer, but I had no luck. Any ideas?

(I know that the clean solution is to introduce a new DLL and to link it properly to the existing DLLs. Unfortunately, this type of solution is beyond the mandate of my team).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear here there is *one* exe with multiple DLL's in only *one* process but multiple modules. So you aren't looking for inter-process communications.

In answer I see two strategies:

1. use Windows API atoms which are slightly limited (basically only string data) which can work within or between processes.
2. If you write a DLL which contains your speculated SetProperty/getproperty functionality you don't have to compile ALL the other DLL's again (which is presumably what is beyond your team's specification) - you only need to recompile those DLL's which are currently using your new features (set/getproperty) (which is presumably within your teams power). So this seems a direct and powerful solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need fancy API's for that. Windows has a much older API precisely for this kind of stuff. These things are known as "atoms". You'd use functions as `AddAtom` and `FindAtom`. By default atoms are process-wide.

Comment: Here's a link to an article that has a wrapper class for use of atoms.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/win32Atom_Wrapper.aspx